# Regarding go tags, should [fuseki] be a synonym for [openings]

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Some Japanese Go terms, such as joseki, don't have an English equivalent. Fuseki, on the other hand, is commonly translated just as "opening". We have a widely used [openings](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openings) tag with a nice, general tag wiki. At least a couple Go questions are tagged with "openings", when they could just as well be tagged "fuseki". Especially for the sake of new members looking for Go questions, I think searching for "fuseki" should return results, but should Go questions prefer "fuseki" to "openings", or should they be synonymized?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use *fuseki* and *opening* exchangeably in practice. http://senseis.xmp.net/?Fuseki supports their equivalence.

Since it is possible to [search](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go+openings) for questions tagged both *go* and *openings*, there is probably no need to keep separate tags.

If there is agreement, I'll merge the tags.

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Comment: Merge performed.